# Azure DevOps Wiki for multiple projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I have newly started exploring capabilities of Azure DevOps Wiki. I have multiple projects in Azure DevOps. I want to create one separate project to store Business & Technical documentation for all my projects in a centralize place. How can I add multiple Wiki pages to keep this organize.

Second question is I have a predefined structure for the documentation. For eg. Purpose Of Application, Local Build Steps, Deployment Steps, Third Party Control used, etc. How can I create & store this as a template so that whenever a new project documentation is to be created this document can be used as a placeholder to be followed by everyone.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I am still working on the solution. But, it looks like I may not be able to use your answer as is. As you mentioned in your answer, If I clone & import wiki from one of my project to the "Documentation" project, there seems no way to do the same for another project. As import repository option is unavailable now.

Comment: After testing, the process of importing wiki repo was not hindered. I can import multiple project wikis into a project repo.  And if you want to add all wikis in the same repo, you could  clone all wikis to local machine, then edit the file structure, and finally git push to the document project. Here is the doc about [the steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops#add-pages-to-your-local-git-repository).

Comment: I struggled with what I imagine to be the same problem. I found that I was defining my "Azure Projects" too fine grained. This resulted in fragmented knowledge (Wikis). Instead I created very few, large, overarching "Azure Projects" each containing many repositories (per application within the project's domain). Then a singular, "Azure Project" level Wiki encompassed all applications, and their shared information. Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add multiple Wiki pages to keep this organize.

In Azure Devops, Wiki is similar to another kind of Repo. You could `Clone Wiki`  to the target project and `Publish the code as wiki`.

Here are the steps:

1. Use the `Clone wiki` option to get the URL from other projects.

[image: Clone Wiki]

2.Navigate to the **target project -> Repos**. Use the `import repository`option to import the wiki to the Repo.

[image: import repository]

3. Use the `Publish Code as wiki` option to publish the repo as wiki page.

[image: Publish wiki]

Here is a doc about [clone wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops).

> How can I create & store this as a template?

Azure Devops doesn't support creating wiki templates now.

Here is [a suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365866/make-it-possible-to-create-wiki-page-based-on-a-te.html) about this feature. You could vote and add comments in this ticket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With this way will I be able to create separate folders per project? & will this information be available under wiki tab or under repos?

Comment: @Jay. This way could provide separate wiki pages per project. This information could be published to Wiki tab. You just need to  use the `Publish the code as wiki` option and select the cloned wiki repo. In other words, the wiki will be cloned into the repo, and then the wiki repo can be published as a wiki page.