# 'Centralized' wiki and repo in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

Living years in confluence+centralized git (bitbucket+github), recently coming to a small shop on MS azure devops, where the repo and wikis scattered between hundred of projects which impossible to find. Would it be a way to structure the azuredevops to make it more 'confluence' like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be a way to structure the azuredevops to make it more 'confluence' like?

I am afraid there is no such a way to structure the azuredevops to make it more 'confluence'.

As we know, the Azure devops is a project-oriented product. Both the repo and the Wiki are based on one project. We can include multiple repo and wiki in a project, but cannot create a repo or wiki for multiple projects.

The workaround is that we could clone Wiki to the target project and Publish the code as wiki, you could check following thread for some more details:

[Azure DevOps Wiki for multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495414/azure-devops-wiki-for-multiple-projects)